# is $f(x)$ bounded at $x_0$ when f(x) is not defined at $x_0$?

Tags: calculus, logic

let $f(x)$ not defined at $x_0$ ,can we say $f(x)$ is bouneded at $x_0$?

here's what I thought:

if $f(x)$ is defined at $x_0$,then $f(x)$ is bounded at $x_0$ since it's only a single point.

but if $f(x)$ not defined at $x_0$, I try to write in some formal way like:

$\exists M\ge 0$ such that if $x=x_0$ then $f(x_0) \le M$
or
if $x=x_0$ then  $\exists M\ge 0$ such that$f(x_0) \le M$

either way,since $x=x_0$  is false, both statement is true.

---

the question is originated from a question:

> True or False : if $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ exists, then $f(x)$ is bounded at $x_0$

the question try to check relation between limit of the point and the point.

but my thought is that $f(x)$ always bounded at $x_0$ no matter $f(x)$ is defined at $x_0$ or not.

Am I right?

Comment: I have never seen anybody use the term 'bounded at $x_0$'.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}$ is neither defined at zero nor bounded around zero.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  ,the original question is not in english. I try my best to translate it. I think the question is try to ask if $f(x)$ is bounded at a point.

Comment: I have never seen anyone talking about a function being bounded at a point. It's much more common to talk about it being bounded on a set / domain (for instance, it would be natural to all whether $f$ was bounded close to $x_0$).

Comment: @Arthur that's why I confuse a lot about the question. The teacher said whether or not $f(x)$ defined at the point $x_0$ or bounded at $x_0$ has nothing to do with the limit exists, so the original question is false.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: if $f$ is not defined at $x_0$, then $f(x_0)$ makes no sense.

Suppose that $f:D \to \mathbb R$ is a function, $x_0 \notin D$ , but $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $D$.

If $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ exists, then there is $ \delta>0$ such that $f$ is bounded on $(D \cap (x_0- \delta, x_0 + \delta)) \setminus \{x_0\}.$

Proof: let $L:=\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x).$ With $ \epsilon=1$ we get that there is $ \delta>0$ such

$|f(x)-L|<1$ for all $x \in (D \cap (x_0- \delta, x_0 + \delta)) \setminus \{x_0\}.$

This gives $|f(x)| =|f(x)-L+L| \le 1+L$ for all $x \in (D \cap (x_0- \delta, x_0 + \delta)) \setminus \{x_0\}.$

q.e.d.

Comment: i can see $f(x)$ is bounded on some neighbor of $x_0$,but the question ask if $f(x)$ is bounded at the point $x_0$, can you say the question is true or false?